# Connecting to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following line of code here, and I've looked everywhere how to connect to a MySQL server in this format, but I can't seem to find out how!

```
$Conn = mysqli_connect("YourMySQLDetails");
```

Usually, I would connect like this:

```
    $myServer = "localhost";
    $myUser = "632496";
    $myPass = "xrxy3749";
    $myDB = "632496";
```

but I get the following error on the webpage

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'YourMySqlDetails' (111)Error:
```

Here is the entire file

```
<?php
$Conn;
CreateDatabase();
function CreateDatabase(){
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","632496","xrxy3749","password","632496");
   if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
 {
      echo "notconnect some Problem Occur";
 }
else
 {
      echo "Connect Successfully";
 }

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
   or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 
 AddTables();   
 }

function AddTables(){
global $Conn;
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql="CREATE TABLE servers(ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 PRIMARY KEY(ID),ServerName CHAR(60),Url CHAR(100),Players INT, MaxPlayers INT, Uptime       INT, LastTimeSeen DATETIME)";

// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($Conn, $sql)){
    echo "Table servers created successfully";
}else{
     echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error();
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Wait a minute. Are you supposed to be using MySQL or MSSQL? They're completely different.

Comment: "Connect to mysql server",, phpmyadmin just a client of mysql server

Comment: Also: I've replaced the word "phpMyAdmin" with "MySQL" - phpMyAdmin is a web-based administrative tool for MySQL.

Comment: I see some calls to `mssql_connect()` and `mssql_select_db()` in your code. These are for MSSQL, not MySQL; they probably don't belong here. (Also, the variables they're using aren't defined.)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the this example. I think your problem solve easily .i have use this example to connect the databse .

```
<?php

  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","632496","xrxy3749","632496");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
     {
          echo "notconnect some Problem Occur";
     }
  else
     {
          echo "Connect Successfully";
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code to connect with mysql database

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","632496","xrxy3749","632496");
```

You have put extra password field  in connection detail.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use mysql and mysqli both function in same file.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","632496","xrxy3749","password","632496");
```

replace it with following code

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","632496","xrxy3749","632496");
```

one more error

```
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
```

replace it with this

```
$dbhandle = mssqli_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass, $dbhandle)
```

remove this code

```
//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
   or die("Couldn't open database $myDB");
```

replace all places

`$Conn to $con`

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to solve your problem

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);
?>
```

Comment: Please do not recommend that people use the deprecated mysql extension.